# Consultation on the Lumer-Phillips Theorem

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

In this proof,  Question 1. why the condition $\left\|(\lambda-A)x\right\|\geq \lambda \left\|x\right\|$ implies the injectivity of the operator $\lambda-A$?

Question 2. Why if $\rho(A)\cap (0,\infty)\neq\emptyset$ implies $A$ is closed?